# jQuery plugin and Mootools conflicts in JOOMLA 1.5.x

Tags: mootools, jquery

I m using Jquery in joomla 1.5.x ( which use mootools internally )
sometimes jquery works fine, but when i use some jQuery plugin then below errors occur

`($(filter) || document).getElementsBySelector is not a function mootools.js( line 53)`

what is the solution of this error

i m already using `jQuery.noConflict()` function before writing jquery code inside `jquery(document).ready(function() { }`

i have seen somewhere about ordering of mootools & jQuery library, that either mootools or jquery code shoud be written first then all code of other library  put together.( i forgot the exact sequence).

please suggest me a perfect solution of this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all its not good idea to use both frameworks in one side. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ to see how jquery noConflict will work. So if you write `jQuery.noConflict()` you have to write `(jQuery(filter) || document).getElementsBySelector`, which you can also use without the noConflict line as `$()` is just an alias vor jQuery().